# Listview height not correct

Tags: android, listview

I used this method to calculate and set listview height at runtime

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/lv_cart" />
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SubTotal:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rs. 600"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/tv_sub_total"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose Order Type:"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#4CAF50"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Delivery"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/btn_delivery"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="PickUp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/btn_pickup"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I debug this method and checked that this method is returning correct height based on children. But when listview is shown then the view in which list is shown is not correct. 
**I added 8 items in my listview but it only shows 5 when I ran it but height that method returned was correct as it showed 1 view height=51 and 8 view height=415 including divider height.**
I also tried listview height in xml with match parent and wrap content but result was same.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Ran into the same issue, this is not a proper solution. I had to revisit my design strategy.

Comment: what you did to solve

Comment: Please post your XML layout too. We may find the cause from that!

Comment: @RuchiraRandana added layout code

Comment: Hi @Vievek. This is not the way to use a listView.
As from what I observe, you are trying to create all the rows at once. You should simply define only the listView in the XML and provide an adapter which would only load the necessary views when required.
Have a look at this tutorial.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

In addition, I've noticed a listView in your XML + a ScrollView. Please note that you cannot use both a ListView and ScrollView together in Android.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: @RuchiraRandana first thing that you don't get is it is a order page, so it shows a list of your orders, restaurant name,address,and many other fields also so that's why there is scrollview. It is not static inflation of data, listview is inflated using adapter only

Answer (score 0):

pleaes try this one :

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, the height here));
```

Comment: If I have to hardcode height then I can do it directly in xml . This is of no use

Comment: are you trying to change the height of the listview? or trying something else? from my understanding you actually want to do that right?

Comment: I want to change listview height but not fix it to some static height